# file manager with tag function as in macOS

Tags: pantheon-files

I read the answers to questions about pantheon files and tags. However, there is not such a helpful solution as in macOS.

My question: Is there a chance to give a monetarian contribution for development of such a solution?

Defining tags which are displayed in tge file manager's sidebar, assign them to files or directories, and search by them just clicking on them.

This would be an excellent function to pantheon.

Answer (score 0):

You can post a bounty for a desired feature at https://www.bountysource.com/teams/elementary

First raise a feature request at https://github.com/elementary/files/issues (after first checking there is not already a similar one). The report should give clear design goals for which the bounty would be awarded.

Probably worth checking that the feature is desired and acceptable to the elementary design team as placing a bounty does not guarantee it will be developed or, if developed, will be accepted, and I am not sure a bounty can be withdrawn once placed.